# Issue with visibility of columns in primefaces datatable after sorting

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I have an issue with the visibility of columns after applying sorting over any of columns.

I am attaching the screen-shots of GUI:

before hiding the colmnns :
[image: before hiding the columns]

After hiding first two columns :
[image: after hiding first two columns]

After applying the sort on the first column after hiding :

[image: After applying the sort on the first column after hiding]

As you can see in the images that sorting the datatable by first column is producing inconsistent results.Below is the code of my datatable:

```
   <composite:implementation>
    <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="item"
                 value="#{cc.attrs.searchAndConsultSecuritiesEntriesResultsPanel.results}"
                 selectionMode="single"
                 selection="#{cc.attrs.searchAndConsultSecuritiesEntriesResultsPanel.selectedItem}"
                 rowKey="#{item.referenceInstruction}"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord}"
                 paginator="true"
                 rows="50"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
                 draggableColumns="true"
                 resizableColumns="true"
                 tableStyle="width: auto"
            emptyMessage="#{applicationMsg['emptylist.label']}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputFormat value="#{applicationMsg['tabview.searchresult.label']}">
                <f:param value="#{cc.attrs.searchAndConsultSecuritiesEntriesResultsPanel.results.size()}"/>
            </h:outputFormat>
            <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="#{applicationMsg['button.columns.label']}"
                             icon="ui-icon-calculator"/>
            <p:columnToggler datasource="tbl" trigger="toggler">
            </p:columnToggler>
        </f:facet>
```

I am completely clueless about this issue.It looks like a bug with Primefaces api.I am using Primefaces vesrion 5.3

Could somebody please help me regarding this

Comment: If you think it is a bug, always, always, always try a newer version (latest) first

Comment: @Kukeltje Right now we can't go for upgrade.Over that I just think it's a bug.I haven't found anything significant about this over internet

Comment: I never said to upgrade. I said to *TRY* a newer version. Just to know if the same thing happens in the latest version too. Only then we know it either still is a bug or was a 'bug' and got fixed

Comment: Oh and btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717800/primefaces-datatable-with-column-toggler-conflicts-with-sort-function-on-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817830/primefaces-columntoggler-doesnt-work-with-pagination and

Comment: @Kukeltje..thank you for direction..:-)

Comment: It seems like the latest version still have bug

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540523/visible-false-unhide-a-column-again-when-sortby-is-clicked